# float label under form element

Tags: css

Trying to have the label.error to show under the select element.  I keep trying a bunch of things with `float` but I'm obviously missing the point.

Here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/ALUQB/5/  Press the "Change timezone" button and see it shows inline.  I want it underneath the select.

Comment: your desired outcome is not possible with the current **HTML** - it can be done with an extra element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a possible solution *(notice the extra `div` element)*:

http://jsfiddle.net/ALUQB/7/

*Adjust the `left` and `bottom` properties as needed*

Comment: I should have told the whole story...it will have more forms on this page. Here is an example of one more form with validation needed: http://jsfiddle.net/ALUQB/16/.  So I'd like to add validation like you helped already but for both forms.  I'm not sure why "Email alerts" is centered in the fiddle as it doesn't look like that on my page.  I should mention that it doesn't have to be just a css solution, adding html is fine.  I imagine a good start to this is adding a div around each form?

Comment: @TomPepernic no - the div needs to wrap the input field `textarea`, `input[type="text"]`, `input[type="check"]` so on and so forth and not the `form`...

Answer (score 0):

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/ALUQB/8/ will work, but if there's another item after it this will cause issues. Fine for the fiddle, at least.

All I've done is absolutely positioned it, banked left, and with a top margin to nudge it down a bit.

Edit: Beaten to the punchline by a few seconds. Either of these solutions will work, neither is particularly ideal/flexible.

Comment: Your solution works with the current example (one form element) but it would "break" when there are other more than one form elements with errors - *the errors would stack*...

Comment: Yep - right you are. I think yours would too. If we can guarantee the width of the select defining a negative margin of that many pixels might be best, but still hacky.

Comment: Mine will not as ***absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their closest explicitly positioned parent*** in my case it is `div.ctrl-container`

Comment: Ahh, I misread your code - right you are. Doesn't answer the original question, but probably more use than mine.

Comment: Does position the error below the `select` - which is the desired behavior. Though, given his current `HTML`, i'm afraid there is no way to achieve the behavior with CSS alone...

Comment: Well there is - my code does that, just it won't work if there are more elements in the form (which there probably are).